# Search files in folder

Tags: dired, find-file

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1
dired+

I want in dired mode find files by `names, content`

1. Approach#1 - use external tools. What tools you can suggest?
2. Approach#2 - use only built-in Emacs function on external lib - What you can suggest?

Comment: If you don't know rgrep and lgrep you should certainly look them up.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking how to find files by matching both their file names and the file contents.  Is that it?

If so, [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) does this for you, in all of its file-finding commands.

The commands use [multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions): The input you type can be two-part: (1) a pattern that matches the file name, (2) a pattern that matches the file content.

You can use only one of the two possible patterns if you like.  For example, you will most often just type a file-name pattern.  In that case, the behavior is like `find-file` (but a very enhanced `find-file`).

When you type input for the command, if you use `C-M-j` that separates the two patterns.  The file-name pattern is first, then `C-M-j`, then the file-content pattern.

This is described in detail here: [File-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input).  The name-and-content-matching behavior is described [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#MatchFileContent).

In Icicles during completion your input patterns can use *regexp* matching (which Icicles calls [*apropos completion*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions)).

---

You ask also about Dired.

In a Dired buffer, there are related content-matching commands you can use to visit the marked files and subdirectories whose content matches a regexp.

`icicle-visit-marked-file-of-content`, bound to `C-S-f`, aka **`C-F`**,
`icicle-visit-marked-file-of-content-recursive`, bound to `M-+ C-F`.

The latter visits not only the files that are marked in the current directory, but also those marked in any marked subdirectories, and sub-subdirectories etc., recursively.  (For these recursively descending searches you need [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).)